# How to compare time after and before midnight?

Tags: time

I have a problem when I am trying to decide if its possible to transfer from one train to another. Conditions are, that arrival (A1) time of the first train must be at least 5 min. before departure of the second train (D2). AND you cannot wait for more than 180 minutes, since you have arrived to the station, for second train to arrive (A2) (You can wait in the second train to departure arbitrarily)?

Time you have to eneter is in format: HH:MM
I did compare those times after I have converted them to minutes elapsed since midnight.

The problem is, that if you want to compare times before midnight with time after midnight, you has to change "if condition" in this cases: A1 and D2 is after midnight but A2 is before midnight, A1 and A2 are before midnight and D2 is after midnight, A1 is before and A2 and D2 is after, A1 and A2 are before midnight (but A2 is sooner) and D2 is after midnight.

In all of those cases you would have to have different condition. How to solve this?

PS: I think I should use different time format (not minutes since midnight), but how?

Thank you!

Comment: What platform\framework\language are you developing on?   Or are you just looking for general psuedocode or approaches?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use 24 hour time. That way if the second time is lower then you know that it rolled over to the next day.

If the second time is lower then all you would have to do is:

```
A1 - D1 = (D)ifference
A1 - D = time before D1 leaves (so the time between A1 and D1)
```

(can someone check my math? I think that is right.)

Answer (score 0):

Don't judge the values based on minutes elapsed since midnight.  Judge them based on their actual values.  Most any programming language you would deal with would have date/time classes/functions that you can use to do simple date subtraction.  If you update your question to indicate what language you are using, I am sure you will be able to get practical code examples.

As a generic UNIX/LINUX practice, for example, you might convert the value to UNIX timestamps and just subtract to get the time difference in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Can you convert to a `DateTime` and then do `DateDiff`?

Pseudocode (syntactically wrong):

```
If DateDiff(minutes, A1, D2) > 5 Then
  If DateDiff(minutes, A1, A2) < 180 Then
    Go ahead and allow the transfer
  else
    Look for another train (too long of a wait)
  end if 'DateDiff(minutes, A1, A2) < 180
  Look for another train (not enough time to transfer)
end if 'DateDiff(minutes, A1, D2) > 5
```

Answer (score -2):

This is what I am working on for a similar problem with Excel:

```
( D3 + IF( (C3-D3)>0,5 ; 1 ; 0 ) ) > ( 0,010417 + C3 + IF( (D3-C3)>0,5 ; 1 ; 0 )  )
```

00:00 = 0 in Excel, 24:00 = 1
I want to know if D3 is more than 15 minutes after C3.
The above formula accomplishes that without having to muck about with dates.
Note the formula depends on C3 and D3 not being more than 12 hours apart, which is always true in my usage scenario so it's no issue.

Laymans terms:
you compare Time1 to (time2 + 15min) but in case there's a midnight switch you check whether the times are more than 12 hours apart and if so add 24h to either Time1 or Time2.

I haven't actually gotten it working yet but that I believe has more to do with Excel being a piece of turd.

In case I overlooked something though be sure to let me know!

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question.  Please refer to the FAQ (stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: Michael, how is it not? I give an example of how to solve his pre-/post-midnight issue without mucking with dates, which is I believe his question.

Thanks for pointing me towards the FAQ, but as it turns out the FAQ mentions nothing about answers, just questions.

I'm new here so please be kind :)

Comment: A couple of things to look at; first it's an old question from a low point user with no updates since it was created, this typically indicates a dead end.  Also you may have inadvertantly given the wrong impression by stating "I haven't actually gotten in working yet"

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. I didn't notice the time of creation. I just noticed that nobody had given an answer similar to mine (which I reckon is the easiest way to solve it). I got it working btw. The issue was that I was using a dutch version of Excel which doesn't recognize the English 'if' as a valid function.